# Calculate average number of direct neighbors in cities in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

In need to calculate the average number of direct neighbors in pre-selected cities in PostGIS.
So far, I have only found solutions to select neighbors based on distance (e.g. all neighbors within 1km from my focal point). 
What I need are really the direct neighbors (so no other points in between) irrespective of the distance.
I have a table where I can select coordinates by cities, e.g. `select lat, lng, geom from mytable where city = 'Munich'` (I have also created a geom column with gist index).
Ideally, I want to calculate for each row in the table (selected by cities) the number of direct neighbors that are also located within the same city.

Comment: 'direct neighbors' can be many things, really; a four/six house wall-to-wall block typical for many older European cities would be most fitting to your description, but that's still the minority of neighborhood relations of house footprints. you'd need to define a threshold, and then using `ST_DWithin` is most likely what you want. even german 'Kataster' data has still gaps, despite the current efforts in optimizing/normalizing official data...

Comment: this comes down very critically to how you define "direct neighbors (so no other points in between) "

Comment: @Ian: My (non-technical) definition would be the following: The direct neighbor has different latitude/longitude, but the location is directly reachable from my location without crossing another location. Does this help?

Comment: are your "locations" areas or points

Comment: location is a latitude/longitude pair

Comment: ...I fear you will find this to be a game of good measures/educated guesses; 'crossing' another location, that is, a *Point* geometry between two others, is like winning the lottery, *if* your locations are not in a perfectly aligned grid. a somewhat more robust way would be to find all points within a defined proximity (for better performance) and check if other points lie within a threshold along the direct line connecting each point pair. but then we're back at defining a threshold.

Comment: It sounds like you might need a graph approach. However, as it stands, your question isnt very clesr. Please edit the question rather than leaving clues in the comments